# Why does the "engine" capitalize this variable. Can it be hidden?

Tags: python, django

The view:

```
 def GRID_ServerDropDownSearch(request):
         if 'r' in request.GET and request.GET['r']:
        r = request.GET['r']
        servers = SERVERS.objects.get(name=r)
    drives = servers.drives_set.all()[0:]
    memory = servers.memory_set.all()[0:]
    return render_to_response('GRID_ServerDropDownSearchResults.html',
    {'servers':servers, 'query':r, 'drives':drives, 'memory':memory})
    else:
    return render_to_response('GRID_search_form.html', {'error': True})
```

The form:

class ServerDropDownForm(forms.Form):

```
r = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = SERVERS.objects.all(), required=False)
```

The template:

```
 <div>
 <form action="/ServerDropDownSearch/" method="GET">
    {{ form.as_table }}
     <input type = "Submit" value = "Submit">
  </form>
  </div>
```

The resulting drop-down form works flawlessly.  However, immediately to the left of the drop-down list is an "R" (capital r).  I know it has to do with the "r" specified in the above code. (If I replace each incidence of r with, say, z then a "Z" appears).  However:

1. WHY does it get capitalized ?  Is this just the default case specified in the engine ?
2. How can I hide that "R" so that, instead, it can indicate "Select A Server", or something more descriptive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "engine", if by that you mean Django, isn't doing anything. If it's capitalized, somewhere in the project's code, it's being capitalized. Not sure if you inherited this or what, but whoever wrote it is seemingly completely unfamiliar with Python coding conventions. Seems more like Django trying to be force fit into a .NET mold.

Comment: Yep, that would be me "completely unfamiliar with Python coding conventions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django derives the label for a form field from the corresponding variable name, but "humanizes" it. For example, a field called `my_variable` would translate to "My variable".

The simplest way to fix this would be to give a more human-readable name to the field:

```
server = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = SERVERS.objects.all(), required=False)
```

However, you can also pass a string to use as the label via the form field's `label` parameter:

```
r = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = SERVERS.objects.all(), required=False, label='Select a server')
```